# Modify XML node value- UpdateXML equivalent for Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xquery, oracle12c

I have some sample code as follows:

```
WITH xtbl AS
         (SELECT 1 AS xtbl_id,
                 xmltype ('<node_root>
                        <node_1>12</node_1>
                        <node_2>233</node_2>
                        <node_3>223</node_3>
                        <node_4>234</node_4>
                   </node_root>') AS x
            FROM Dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, xmltype ('<node_root>
                        <node_1></node_1>
                        <node_2>233</node_2>
                        <node_3>223</node_3>
                        <node_4>234</node_4>
                   </node_root>')
            FROM Dual)
SELECT xtbl_id,
       x,
       Updatexml (x,
                  '/node_root/node_2',
                  NULL,
                  '/node_root/node_3',
                  NULL,
                  '/node_root/node_4',
                  NULL)
           AS xcol
  FROM xtbl
 WHERE (SELECT node_1
          FROM Xmltable ('node_root'
                         PASSING x
                         COLUMNS node_1 INTEGER PATH 'node_1'))
           IS NOT NULL;
```

My requirement is that whenever `/node_root/node_1` in column `x` is not null then replace the values for `/node_root/node_2`, `/node_root/node_3` and `/node_root/node_4` to null. The `Updatexml` function I have used in my `SELECT` query does the same.

The problem here is that `Updatexml` doesn't work in Oracle 12c. This is why I have used `Xmltable` in the subquery and it works perfect at filtering the data, but I am not able to replace the node values with null.

I tried looking at [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5111) for XQuery but couldn't understand how it can be helpful at replacing node values.

Kindly provide a descriptive example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle documentation [recommends to use XQuery to update XML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions235.htm#SQLRF06172). So it's first thing to try.

First, it's possible with old approach with function. XQuery below may be used instead of call to `XmlUpdate`:

```
    XMLQuery(
      ' 
        declare function local:copy-replace($element as element()) {  
          if ($element/self::node_2) then <node_2/>
          else if ($element/self::node_3) then <node_3/>
          else if ($element/self::node_4) then <node_4/>
          else element {node-name($element)}  
                       {$element/@*, 
                        for $child in $element/node()  
                        return if ($child instance of element())  
                               then local:copy-replace($child)  
                               else $child  
                       }  
        };  
        local:copy-replace($p/*)
      '
      passing x as "p" returning content
    ) as xcol_2
```

Another, shorter and more intuitive variant:

```
    XMLQuery(
      '              
        copy $p2 := $p
        modify(
          replace value of node $p2/node_root/node_2 with "",
          replace value of node $p2/node_root/node_3 with "",
          replace value of node $p2/node_root/node_4 with ""
        )
        return $p2
      '
      passing x as "p" returning content
    ) as xcol_3
```

And in addition, it's possible to return a modified XML value only if condition not matched:

```
WITH xtbl AS
     (SELECT 1 AS xtbl_id,
             xmltype ('<node_root>
                    <node_1>12</node_1>
                    <node_2>233</node_2>
                    <node_3>223</node_3>
                    <node_4>234</node_4>
               </node_root>') AS x
        FROM Dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, xmltype ('<node_root>
                    <node_1></node_1>
                    <node_2>233</node_2>
                    <node_3>223</node_3>
                    <node_4>234</node_4>
               </node_root>')
        FROM Dual)
SELECT xtbl_id,
   x,
    XMLQuery(
      '   
        for $test in $p/*
        return 
          if( empty($p/node_root/node_1/text()) )             
            then $p
            else (
             copy $p2 := $p
              modify(
                replace value of node $p2/node_root/node_2 with "",
                replace value of node $p2/node_root/node_3 with "",
                replace value of node $p2/node_root/node_4 with ""
              )
              return $p2
           )   
      '
      passing x as "p" returning content
    ) as xcol_4
FROM xtbl
```

So there are many variants to perform operations on XML values, but this requires deeper knowledge of [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/) and [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) than a relatively simple XmlUpdate function ...

Comment: The first code example works in 11gR2 as well as 12c. The second and third examples work only in 12c. Thanks!

Comment: It's strange because I test all variants against 11.2.0.3 version of Oracle. Can you please post exact version of your Oracle (e.g. `select * from v$version`)?

Comment: There are two- 11.2.0.1.0 and 12.1.0.1.0, both 64bit.

Comment: Loooks like working since 11.2.0.3. Look at [this page](http://technology.amis.nl/2011/09/22/oracle-xmldb-xquery-update-in-database-release-11-2-0-3-0/) (sorry, can't find official proof).

Comment: No problem. Your first example runs in 11.2.0.1 and that's enough for me. Thanks!