# how to update specific attribute in xml of clob column in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I have a CLOB column, where I need to update the value of one of the attribute in the xml(CLOB). For example

```
<discounts>
                    <code>ZSP3M</code>
                    <description>50% discount 3 months</description>
                    <discountAmount>0</discountAmount>
                    <discountPercent>0.50</discountPercent>
                    <amount>0</amount>
                    <financeCode>PROMOS</financeCode>
                    <startDate>2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z</startDate>
                    <enddate>2014-06-30T00:00:00.000Z</enddate>
                    <discountType>Group</discountType>
                    <tax>0</tax>
                    <sequenceid>1</sequenceid>
                    <discountDuration>0</discountDuration>
</discounts>
```

I need to update `<discountAmount>0</discountAmount> with <discountAmount>200</discountAmount>`,

I tried some thing like

```
update order set order_xml = to_clob(' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><discounts>
                    <code>ZSP3M</code>
                    <description>50% discount 3 months</description>
                    <discountAmount>0</discountAmount>
                    <discountPercent>0.50</discountPercent>
                    <amount>0</amount>
                    <financeCode>PROMOS</financeCode>
                    <startDate>2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z</startDate>
                    <enddate>2014-06-30T00:00:00.000Z</enddate>
                    <discountType>Group</discountType>
                    <tax>0</tax>
                    <sequenceid>1</sequenceid>
                    <discountDuration>0</discountDuration>
</discounts>') where ordernumber = 'XXXX';
```

it works for small xml, I don't want to update full xml insted just wanted to update only on attribute of xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your XML as CLOB you have no other way than rewriting the entire CLOB value.

However, if you store the XML as [XMLTYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30024) you have the entire XPath capabilities of [Oracle XML DB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/toc.htm) to your disposal, including [XQuery Update](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB0440). Have a look at [this question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016083/modify-xml-node-value-updatexml-equivalent-for-oracle-12c/21021822#21021822)